# Docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have production docker swarm instalation

Im my CI I have regular launch of

```
docker run --network prod_default ...
```

Sometimes it fails with error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make
sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context
deadline exceeded.
```

Any ideas about reason ? or how to fix it?

Comment: You should first check if your network prod_default is attachable.

```docker inspect --format='{{.Attachable}}' prod_default```.

Answer (score 1):

set your all nodes to `active` state:

```
docker node update --availability active node02
```

see more [here](https://success.docker.com/article/context-deadline-exceeded-error-observed-while-starting-container-on-drained-node)

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late but make sure the ***ENGINE VERSION*** is the same for both of your nodes

You can check the version with:

```
sudo docker node ls
```